# Why am I getting a different look with Huey Pro on a LED TV screen?

Tags: troubleshooting, color-management, display-calibration, monitors, huey

I own a Huey Pro and used it on CRTs, LCDs and my Mac Book Pro screen.
Been using it fine with these screens until I bought a LED monitor.

When calibrated with the Huey pro the LED monitor (connected to my MBP) shows me a quite different look compared to what I see on the MBP screen (Lightroom4 & Photoshop CS6).  This wasn't the case with the other aforementioned calibrated screens connected to the MBP.

Is there something I need to do with the LED controls? The backlight? The brightness? The contrast?

When I was using the CRT & LCD I used to turn brightness all the way down and increase the contrast on the monitors before calibration. So, I'm suspecting the the LED backlight but can't be quite sure whether to turn it off or what to do exactly.

Also my MBP has an anti glare screen... if this can help.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The huey Pro is a colorimeter, not a photospectrometer. What this means is that it does not measure the full spectrum of light, but rather, it can only measure one spectrum of light. Now, it does this three times, through three different and precisely calibrated color filters. If you turn your huey over and look at the business end, you can see the glint of three of these filters.

These filters need to match the basic red, green, and blue that the monitor displays.

My guess here is that the three filters do not match the red green and blue that your LED display produces.

What can you do to fix it? Nothing that I'm aware of.  I'd try contacting Pantone and see what they say. You could try borrowing a ColorMunki (which is a photospectrometer) and see if that works better. It is significantly more expensive however.

Comment: Bought a ColorMunki, everything much better after that. Thank you & sorry for late reply.

Comment: I only just came across this, very interesting, as my Huey worked perfectly well on my CCFL (Viewsonic) LCD monotors, but made my laptop (LED LCD) look terrible.